# Python -basemap: issue with longitude convention, how to plot tectonic boundaries through 180°

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, matplotlib-basemap

I am new at plotting maps with Python matplotlib-basemap (usually using GMT but need a way that can easily be used to plot maps for teaching). 
I want to plot a map of Indonesia up to middle Pacific, between 90°E and 160°W - so far so good - on which I want to plot the tectonic boundaries. 
I downloaded what looks like the officiel the database of tectonic plates: https://github.com/fraxen/tectonicplates
including shapefiles.

There's apparently an incompatibility with the longitude convention between 0/360° vs 180/-180, and I cannot get the tectonic boundaries to cross 180° !!

Here is my code, attached is the results :

```
m  = Basemap(llcrnrlon=90.,urcrnrlon=220.,llcrnrlat=-30.,urcrnrlat=70.,\
            resolution='h',projection='gall', lon_0=240.,lat_0=20.)
m.readshapefile('tectonicplates-master/PB2002_boundaries', 
            name='Pacific', 
            drawbounds=True, 
            color='blue', zorder=2)

m.drawcoastlines()

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-30,65,20),labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(90,220,30),labels=[0,0,0,1])
```

I tried different projections, nothing works and I don't know if it is possible and if so how to select a specific region with readshapefile, maybe to execute it twice between 0/180 and -180/0...

Has anyone ever had this issue and found a solution ?

[Indonesia-Pacific](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw46x.png)

Comment: Tried downloading some of the shapefiles but am unable to open them in OGR or ArcMap/QGIS- are you sure these are valid shapefiles?

Comment: I think because it does plot plate boundaries anywhere else and up to 180° (cf figure 'Indonesia-Pacific')..